# How to add security properties of pdf while generating PDF from HTML using javascript?

Tags: angular, laravel, pdf, pdfmake, maatwebsite-excel

I am developing an Angular 4 project with PHP/ Laravel backend.

There are two ways I can generate PDF: -
1. Using pdfMake at frontend
2. Using dompdf or maatwebsite or any other laravel library by sending request to backend

Both of the above ways are enough to generate a plain PDF.

**The problem is I want to add some security feature of PDF before the file gets generated viz. No content copying, No Print,page extraction, etc.** Thus when the pdf is downloaded by the user, these features should be implemented in that particular pdf.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Make use of fpdf.
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script37.php

Comment: also refer this https://packagist.org/packages/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf?q=&p=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sovled the issue with laravel PHP.

reference link:- https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html

Also, https://packagist.org/packages/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf?q=&p=2

1. composer require niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf
2. go to config/app.php and add below lines

   'providers' => [
       // ...
       niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\PdfServiceProvider::class
   ]
   'aliases' => [
       // ...
       'PDF' => niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\Facades\Pdf::class
   ]
3. Run this command from terminal - php artisan vendor:publish
4. Basic pdf generation-- code in PHP

   use PDF;
   function generate_pdf() {
       $data = [
           'foo' => 'bar'
       ];
       $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
       return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
   }

// other opptions are save($filename), download($filename), output()
5. set protection using

```
use PDF;
function generate_pdf() {
    $data = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
    $pdf->SetProtection(['copy', 'print'], '', 'pass');
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
}
```

// pass blank array in set protection instead of copy and print to deny all permissions to users

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, both of the packages do not support any such features yet. See this [open issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1262) for `pdfMake` and this yet [unmerged PR](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/pull/277) for laravel `dompdf`.

Though you can fork [dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) yourself and try out the changes.